# Erorr al abrir ventana modal

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap, modal

Tengo un problema a la hora de abrir cualquier ventana modal, se me queda la ventana oscurecida y no puedo interactuar con la página, la cuestion es que solo ocurre cuando está la linea `<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}'>`
Pero si la quito no funciona correctamente el nav :/
Aqui el codigo completo

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="script" type='application/javascript' href='{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}'>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='{{ asset('css/unsemantic-grid-responsive.css') }}'>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ asset('css/estilos.css') }}'>
</head>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top">
    <p class="titulo">Titulo</p>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href='{{route('home')}}' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('servicios')}}" class="btn btn-menu btn-lg">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='{{route('login')}}' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Área cliente</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='#' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='#' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Contacto</a>
            </li>
            @if(session()->has('validado')||session()->has('adminvalidado'))
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{route('logout')}}">Cerrar sesion</a>
                </li>

            @endif

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flipFlop">
    Click
</button>
<!-- The modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="flipFlop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Flip-flop</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                A type of open-toed sandal.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pueden ser dos cosas, una que tu archivo estilos.css esté sobrescribiendo alguna clase de bootstrap que se usa en el modal, y otra es que tu archivo bootstrap.min.js debería estar después del link a la cdn de JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema reside en la estructura de tu HTML. Hay varias reglas de recomendación habitual que te estás saltando. Te dejo enlace a las convenciones y recomendaciones en estructura y sintaxis de HTML
https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#syntax
https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics.html#semantics

1º y mas importante la estructura de tu HTML, tienes un "nav" entre Head y body. No debería ir ahí. Debe ir contenido dentro del body, y principalmente por las convenciones,en segundo lugar porque bootstrap trabaja correctamente dentro del body.
Sus selectores frecuentemente utilizan el body para obtener el elemento, tanto en JS como en CSS, por lo que todo lo que esté fuera, dará problemas.

2º el código Javascript siempre se debe colocar al final, DENTRO, antes de cerrar el body. Todo ese código Javascript de la cabecera solo relentiza la carga de la misma

3º SIEMPRE neceista estar la librería de Jquery antes que la de bootstrap, en otro caso da problemas y no funciona.

Y la solución tan sencillo como poner dentro del body todo :)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top">
    <p class="titulo">Titulo</p>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href='' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-menu btn-lg">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Área cliente</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='#' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href='#' class='btn btn-menu btn-lg'>Contacto</a>
            </li>


        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flipFlop">
    Click
</button>
<!-- The modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="flipFlop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Flip-flop</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                A type of open-toed sandal.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como ves, es tu mismo código simplemente he suprimido la parte que carga las plantillas blade por php "{{}}". El resto está todo igual.Solo copiar, y pegar dentro del body, los javascript al final y siempre en el orden Jquery > Bootstrap.js

Espero que te ayude :)

Saludos!

Comment: Gracia! Ya funciona correctamente :)